# java and regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a regular expression in order to use it in java using pattern and matcher.
the regular expression should test if a word inside a text is surrounded by javascript tags.
For examples, lets say i have the following text:

```
**testtesttesttest <script> example of a "text" </script> testtesttesttest**
```

and i need to check if the word "text" is surrounded by <script> and </script>.

I have split the text to have two texts:

```
txt1 = testtesttesttest <script> example of a 
txt2 = </script> testtesttesttest
```

Now i need to check:

1. if txt1 contains the tag <script> but does not contain after it a tag </script>
2. if txt2 contains the tag </script> but does not contain before it a tag <script>

Is there a way to do it using the regular expression?
Thank you in advance,

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do it using regular expressions.

Comment: Using regex to parse HTML is never a good idea:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expression is not a good idea

Comment: For the described problem a regular expression is just fine and will do the job. It is not a context sensitive problem (where a push down automaton would be necessary) to check whether there's one opening and one closing surrounding tag!

Answer (score 0):

First you can get inside of your javascript tag with regular expessions.

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<script>(.+?)</script>");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("**testtesttesttest <script> example of a \"text\" </script> testtesttesttest**");
    matcher.find();
    String insdeOfTag= matcher.group(1);
```

Then, you can check if string contains "text"

```
insdeOfTag.contains("text");
```

You can loop all the results with this:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
        values.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```

The values list will contain the texts inside the javascript tags.

```
for (String text : values) {
//you can look for the word "text" on a specific index in here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the text might contain multiple word "text" inside script tags, and in my case i need to do the check on a word "text" on a specific index, so i will need to loop all the results of matcher and check if the word "text" has the same index.